# In Spark 1.6 / Scala, getting column value correlated with aggregate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a DataFrame with three columns:

```
itemid, date, price
1, 2017-05-18, $1.10
2, 2017-05-18, $2.20
1, 2017-04-12, $0.90
1, 2017-03-29, $1.00
```

Now, I want to group by itemid, get the earliest date, and get the price that matches the earliest date. (We can assume (itemid, date) is unique.)

The output for the input above would be:

```
1, 2017-03-29, $1.00
2, 2017-05-18, $2.20
```

In SQL, I can do this using a self-join -- first select the minimum date for each itemid, and then select the price and date where the date matches that minimum date.

How do I express this in Scala Spark DataFrames?
If the answer still involves the self-join, is the DataFrame query executor in Spark 1.6 smart enough to not actually materialize the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use SparkSQL window function similar to the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq(
    (1, "2017-05-18", 1.10),
    (2, "2017-05-18", 2.20),
    (1, "2017-04-12", 0.90),
    (1, "2017-03-29", 1.00)
  ).toDF(
    "itemid", "date", "price"
  ).as[(Integer, String, Double)]

// Add earliest date by itemid via window function and
// keep only rows with earliest date by itemid
val df2 = df.withColumn("earliestDate", min("date").over(
    Window.partitionBy("itemid")
  )).
  where($"date" === $"earliestDate")

df2.show
+------+----------+-----+------------+
|itemid|      date|price|earliestDate|
+------+----------+-----+------------+
|     1|2017-03-29|  1.0|  2017-03-29|
|     2|2017-05-18|  2.2|  2017-05-18|
+------+----------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It turns out, this is somewhat similar to the self-join approach -- because (itemid, date) is already a guaranteed unique key, I can calculate the min-price-for-id-by-date using standard aggregates, and then re-join on that. I e, instead of using a row id, I can use the unique key, and instead of using windowing, I can just use groupBy().

Comment: @Jon Watte, yes, using groupBy and self-join with (itemid, date) being unique, there is no need for creating a unique column.  In fact, in this simple case, there is no need for self-join (therefore certainly no need for creating a unique rowid) if window function is used.  I've updated my answer.